# Comparing UTF-8 letterlike symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, utf-8, hex

I have an HTML document that looks something like this:

```
...
<p>Ambient temperature:</p>
<p class="big"><span id="ambientTempValue">23.6</span> <span id="ambientTempUnit">&#8451;</span></p>
...
```

I want to compare the value of #ambientTempUnit to check whether it's Fahrenheit or Celsius, but since the unit is in hex encoded format, jQuery simply returns the decoded version (degree of Celsius in this example).
So, the question is, how can I compare those. There's probably a function that decodes the hex value but I had no luck finding it on Google.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's a decimal number, formulated as a XML character reference.

```
$('<span>&#8451;</span>').text() === String.fromCodePoint(8451);
$('<span>&#8451;</span>').text().charCodeAt(0) === 8451;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Ambient temperature:</p>
<p class="big"><span id="ambientTempValue">23.6</span> <span id="ambientTempUnit">&#8451;</span></p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
if(document.getElementById("ambientTempUnit").innerHTML == "℃"){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "It's like totaly celsius man";
}
if(document.getElementById("ambientTempUnit").innerHTML == "℉"){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "It's like totaly fahrenheit man";
}
if(document.getElementById("ambientTempUnit").innerHTML == "K"){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "It's like totaly kelvin man";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```